# 'this' keyword is not reliable for prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

Suppose I want to use the prototype pattern in Javascript:

```
function Complimenter(compliment) {
    this.complimentWord = compliment;
}

Complimenter.prototype.printCompliment = function(str) {
    console.log(str + " is " + this.complimentWord);
};
```

This seems to make sense:

```
var complimenter = new Complimenter("beautiful");
complimenter.printCompliment("a flower");
//prints: "a flower is beautiful"
```

However, not always, because 'this' can be hijacked to becoming something else:

```
var stuff = ["a flower", "the moon"];
stuff.forEach(complimenter.printCompliment); //prints:
//"a flower is undefined"
//"the moon is undefined"
```

any ideas on how to use 'this' without giving up on '.prototype'? 
The solutions I've found so far:

- Using `var _this = this` (but this won't work with .prototype)
- Using .bind(), but it is ugly and redundant: `complimenter.printCompliment.bind(complimenter)`

What do you think?

Comment: The value of this always depends on the execution context, i.e. how the function was called, not how it was defined.

Comment: I know how 'this' works, but how can I use it reliably in a .prototype?